# MySQL: count groups of results

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table that looks a bit like this:

```
ID
word
timestamp
```

now I need a result that looks like this:

```
word (unique)
total number of records for this word
total number of records for this word between date1 and date 2
total number of records for this word between date2 and date 3
```

that is: i need the list for all (unique) words (which i could achieve with a GROUP BY clause) and the counts for the respective timeslots.

While i know how to achieve this with multiple queries and some PHP, i wonder if it is possible to create a single (thus more performant) table.

Can anyone help me there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, instead of counting you're summing, because the boolean expressions return either `true` or `false`, that is the same as `1` or `0`.

```
SELECT
word,
COUNT(*) AS 'total number of records for this word',
SUM(timestamp BETWEEN $date1 AND $date2) AS 'total number of records for this word between date1 and date 2',
SUM(timestamp BETWEEN $date2 AND $date3) AS 'total number of records for this word between date2 and date 3'
FROM your_table
GROUP BY word;
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that SUM() would add up the occurances of timestamps. I would have expected some weird dates as a result of that.